# Oracle SQL Count of a field Grouped by another field

Tags: sql, oracle, count, group-by, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a small query below which i want to have a Count of each `HOUSE_ID` and Grouped By `LOCATION_ID` however it is not grouping by `LOCATION_ID` because the `HOUSE_ID`'s are different. I want it to count `HOUSE_ID`'s by `LOCATION_ID`'s regardless of the `HOUSE_ID`.

**QUERY**

```
SELECT 
COUNT(HOUSE_ID) AS Count,
LOCATION_ID,
ZONE,
AREA
FROM TABLE
WHERE SITE_ID = 'ABC'
AND LOCATION_ID NOT LIKE ('%LAND%')
GROUP BY LOCATION_ID, HOUSE_ID, ZONE, AREA
```

**Expected Result**

```
_____________________________
|Count|LOCATION_ID|ZONE|AREA|
|¯¯¯¯¯|¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯|¯¯¯¯|¯¯¯¯|
|  4  |  LOCA     | 2  |  1 |
|  7  |  LOCB     | 6  |  2 |
|  3  |  LOCC     | 3  |  1 |
|  9  |  LOCD     | 5  |  7 |
|  6  |  LOCE     | 7  |  4 |
|  2  |  LOCF     | 2  |  1 |
|  8  |  LOCG     | 7  |  5 |
|  7  |  LOCH     | 9  |  1 |
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
```

**Actual Result**

```
_____________________________
|Count|LOCATION_ID|ZONE|AREA|
|¯¯¯¯¯|¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯|¯¯¯¯|¯¯¯¯|
|  1  |  LOCA     | 2  |  1 |
|  1  |  LOCA     | 6  |  2 |
|  1  |  LOCA     | 3  |  1 |
|  1  |  LOCA     | 5  |  7 |
|  1  |  LOCA     | 7  |  4 |
|  1  |  LOCA     | 2  |  1 |
|  1  |  LOCA     | 7  |  5 |
|  1  |  LOCA     | 9  |  1 |
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
```

Comment: dude, may I ask you to stop this thing with adding irrelevant tags to random posts?

Comment: They all seem relevant to the question there asking?
If there are any you deem irrelevant that wont help more people find the question to possibly answer it then i would happily remove them.

Comment: I don't feel like to follow you all the day, revising your edits. Such a serial re-tagging is frowned upon in general. It's ok to fix a tag or two for a question you come across. But as a constant occupation it's better for find yourself another business. Answering questions for example.

Comment: Im not saying you, as in you, you as in the 'community'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, Needed to Count(*)!!

```
SELECT 
COUNT(*) AS Count,
SUM(AREA) AS AREA
LOCATION_ID,
ZONE,
FROM TABLE
WHERE SITE_ID = 'ABC'
AND LOCATION_ID NOT LIKE ('%LAND%')
GROUP BY LOCATION_ID, ZONE
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove `HOUSE_ID` from group by clause.
Without source data I can only guess that you also need agregate functions for `ZONE` and `AREA` column, `MAX` fro example. Try below solution:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(HOUSE_ID) AS Count,
LOCATION_ID,
MAX(ZONE),
MAX(AREA)
FROM TABLE
WHERE SITE_ID = 'ABC'
AND LOCATION_ID NOT LIKE ('%LAND%')
GROUP BY LOCATION_ID
```

Comment: I think i have found the issue, i want to count by houseID however each house id is different, i want to have a count of each house ID per locationID regardless of what the house IDs are

Comment: Maybe, but without data from the table it's hard to guess which solution is good.

Comment: Re worded my original question.. I want it to count HOUSE_ID's by LOCATION_ID's regardless of the HOUSE_ID.

Comment: @Matt Could you include data from the table? It will be very helpful.

Comment: Just whats in the question, its just a count of everything HOUSE_ID per LOCATION_ID but i cant get the code to work

Comment: @Matt I've change the answer try it now please.

Comment: Got it! needed to Count(*)